# Having trouble with sqlite, fmdb and swift

Tags: xcode, sqlite, swift, xcode6

I am really confused on how to use sqlite with Swift. My INSERT queries get executed without any errors but when I open the database the data that should have been added is not there. I am using the FMDB wrapper.

Here is my code:

```
let documentsFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String

let path = documentsFolder.stringByAppendingPathComponent("currencylite.db")

let database = FMDatabase(path: path)

if !database.open() {
        println("Unable to open database")
        return

    } else {
        if database.open() {

let querySQL = "INSERT INTO currencyrates (baseccy, matchccy, rateccy, date) VALUES ('\(base)', '\(currency)', \(frate), '\(updtdate)')"
println(querySQL)                            

 database.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
    }
```

`println(querySQL)` echoes `INSERT INTO currencyrates (baseccy, matchccy, rateccy, date) VALUES ('AUD', 'ZAR', 9.3683, '2015-06-25')`So I am pretty sure it doesn't come from the data but from the way I execute the query ...

Edit:

After executing the query I look at both sqlite databases the one in the project folder and the one in the Document folders and both are not getting updated ... I can read the content fine though, I just can't insert ...

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
if !database.executeUpdate("insert into currencyrates (baseccy, matchccy, rateccy, date) values (?, ?, ?, ?)", withArgumentsInArray: [base, currency, NSNumber(double: frate), updtdate]) {
println("insert 1 table failed: \(database.lastErrorMessage())")
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do it like this:

```
let documentsFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String

let path = documentsFolder.stringByAppendingPathComponent("currencylite.db")

let database = FMDatabase(path: path)

if !database.open() {
    println("Unable to open database")
    return

} else {
    if database.open() {

let querySQL = "INSERT INTO currencyrates (baseccy, matchccy, rateccy, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
println(querySQL)                            

database.executeQuery(querySQL, baseccy, matchccy, NSNumber(double: rateccy), date)
}
```

assuming:
`baseccy: String`, `matchccy: String`, `rateccy: Double`, `date: String`